# Retrieve a specific node from a $(xData.responseXML) object

Tags: sharepoint, jquery-selectors, spservices

I'm completely stuck in retrieving a specific node from a responseXML object that I got back from the `GetUserProfileByName` (SharePoint / SPServices). I need a specific `PropertyData` node (in the example "FirstName") and then retrieve the value of the "FirstName". Retrieving the value is not a problem, retrieving the specific node is...

Below a part from the returned XML (for the sake of the example I stripped some properties):

```
...
<PropertyData>
   <Name>UserProfile_GUID</Name>
   <Values>
     <ValueData>
       <Value xmlns:q1="...">206b47c7-cfdc-...</Value>
     </ValueData>
   </Values>
</PropertyData>
<PropertyData>
   <Name>FirstName</Name>
   <Values>
     <ValueData>
       <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Maarten</Value>
     </ValueData>
   </Values>
</PropertyData>
...
```

Since I know that I need the property `FirstName`, I do not want to iterate through the entire set of `PropertyData` nodes until I've the correct one (slow). In XPath I can select `FirstName` just by saying:

```
//PropertyData[Name='FirstName']/Values/ValueData/Value
```

However, I cannot do that in the `xData.responseXML` object. I tried the following filter, finds and other things (in all kinds of variations):

```
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("PropertyData").find("[Name*=FirstName]")

$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("PropertyData").find("[Name*='FirstName']")

$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("PropertyData").filter("[Name*=FirstName]")

$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("PropertyData[Name='FirstName']")
```

I did many searches, but was not able to find an answer. There were many partial answer which a I all tried, but were not working. Any one a clue...

Thanks in advance!
Maarten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Maarten
I'm not at my computer right now to test, but try this:

```
$(xData.responseXML).find("Name:contains('FirstName')").closest("PropertyData")
```

**REVISION 1:**
Given your feedback that an additional element is returned (the phonetic field), here is a revised selector to only return the one containing the FirstName element:

```
$(xData.responseXML)
     .find("Name:contains('FirstName')")
     .not(":contains('SPS-PhoneticFirstName')")
     .closest("PropertyData");
```

Paul

Comment: Paul, this seems to work. I still check if there are more `FirstName` elements. I got 2 nodes back, one for `FirstName` and a second one for `SPS-PhoneticFirstName`. But I can live with that, better than iterating through 50 nodes!

Comment: I revised the same above to remove the phonetic field and only return the PropertyData node containing the FirstName field.

Comment: Paul, thanks again! It's working for me now. However I did not implement your last revision. I wrote a function which retrieves a passed SP Profile property name. Therefor I'm not able to exclude anything since I do not know what kind of custom properties there are.